# How could I be notified of a new Facebook comment on any of my site's pages?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've a site, say, example.com with many individual pages that are created dynamically (example.com/a/, example.com/b/ etc), each of which has its own Facebook Comment box.

Is it possible for me to be notified whenever a user comments in any one of those pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the facebook-graph-api documentation about the "Subscription" object which looks like it should be possible to set up callbacks that you need when posts are made to a particular page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/subscription/

However you ask in particular about comments, and there's a comment on this page about exactly this point - it leads you over to this post -
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5957007/facebook-graph-api-subscription-to-posts-notes

Here @bigtallbill just seems to be suggesting that the subscription and callback is not giving a complete or reliable feed of the comments and he talks about doing polling instead (and then links to batchapi presumably to manage the number of queries needed.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5957007/facebook-graph-api-subscription-to-posts-notes